# Is Cxf modify Outbound Response Message?

Tags: spring, cxf, charset

I'm making Web service using CXF,
nd i didn't set any Interceptor or message Capture.
When i return Response my data charset is modified.

my service code like this

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Respnse test(@Context HttpHeaders header,
                    @RequestBody String body) {
    String result = 'some make String logic'
    return Response.status(200)
                   .encoding("euc-kr")
                   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml;charset=euc-kr")
                   .entity(result)
                   .build();
}
```

I'm sure "result" String has EUC-KR charset.
But, when client received Response Message this String
English, Number char is fine, but other language is crashed.

So i just suspect cxf modify outbound some how.
I'm using CXF 3.1.x version.